# Copying one partition at a time doesn’t result in a bootable drive. Why? How to fix?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Instead of using clone software, I wanted to copy, one at a time, each partition on my C: boot drive to a larger drive. I did this with no errors (used mini wizard to copy one at a time)

I thought it should boot but on reboot I hit <kbd>f12</kbd> to choose the new drive, but it was not in the list of bootable devices.

So do I have to make one of the partitions active? (I thought it might have already been that way because I copied the originals with there attributes.)

Or will this method not work for other reasons, the boot drive is GPT partition?

The source drive is a 1TB Windows 10 drive and the destination disk is a 2TB drive.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Copying partitions probably means that the *partition* UUIDs might not have been copied (since they reside in the partition table). You could have get the partition type wrong when you create the partition table on the destination drive. Besides Some software may intentionally change the *filesystem* (UU)IDs as well. Either way, make sure you don't attempt to boot the destination drive with the source drive attached. You may also want to clarify how / at what point did the booting fail.

Comment: So this is a GPT-partitioned drive, correct? Did you recreate the EFI boot entry? Did you copy over the EFI System Partition? (“Active” partitions aren’t a thing on GPT.) Do all partitions have the expected type?